# Create certificates from .p12 file - NGINX, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have .p12 file from third party service from which I want to create certificates and add them to NGINX.

What I do is to move the p12 file in the server and then create the pem file:

`openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -in server-cert-key-bundle.p12 -out server-ca-cert-bundle.pem`,

then create the key file:

`openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -nodes -in server-cert-key-bundle.p12 -out server.key`

and the config for that domain:

`ssl_certificate /var/www/folder/conv/server-ca-cert-bundle.pem; ssl_certificate_key /var/www/folder/conv/server.key;`

, but in the browser, I see a privacy error:

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

In the [SSL checker](https://decoder.link/sslchecker), the errors are:

> Doesn't match Common Name or/and SANs

> The order of certificates is invalid or certificates cannot build certification path

> We were unable to verify this certificate

In [GlobalSign](https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/analyze.html):

> Certificate name mismatch

I have other domains with Let's Encrypt certificates

With `openssl verify ...pem`:

> 

error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error ......pem: verification failed

I see that `CN` is different than the domain name.

Comment: For over a decade **most HTTPS certs use SAN (SubjectAlternativeName)** and then CN (CommonName) is ignored and irrelevant. Use `openssl x509 -in file -text [-noout]` to check if your cert has SAN and if so whether at least one entry in it is correct for your server; if not, you must either get a corrected cert or change the server (if possible) to match the cert. This is especially true for LetsEncrypt; all certs issued by LE since it started have used SAN. Also, use of a p12 file to move the cert is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Were you perhaps visiting the IP address of the site in your browser, and checking the IP address using SSL Checker?  If so, the IP address will almost never match the name(s) listed on the certificate, and could explain the issues you encountered.